# xerces c++ and cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, xerces

i tryng to build a small example of Xerces with xerces c++ 3.1 and cmake, but i and only getting linkings problems.
This is my cmkelists.txt:

```
//============================================================================
project(ConfiguradorXerces)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include_directories (/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/src)
link_directories (/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/.libs)
link_directories (/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/xerces/xerces-c-3.1.1/src/)
set ( XercesLib  xerces-c )
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${XercesLib})
//==============================================
```

//===============================================

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
using namespace xercesc;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    try {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
      }
      catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
        // Do your failure processing here
        return 1;
      }

      // Do your actual work with Xerces-C++ here.

      XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

      // Other terminations and cleanup.
      return 0;
}
```

//==============================================

and this is my console output:

```
CMakeFiles/ConfiguradorXerces.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const*, char const*, xercesc_3_1::PanicHandler*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()'
CMakeFiles/ConfiguradorXerces.dir/main.cpp.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_1::XMLException'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ConfiguradorXerces] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ConfiguradorXerces.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
16:28:55: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project ConfiguradorXerces (target: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

//
i was thinking trhat my cmakeLsits.txt was not complete, there is an especial setup that it has to be done??
thx in advance

Comment: Care to share your CMake config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that `target_link_libraries()` macro accepts a target as its first parameter:

```
  target_link_libraries(<target> [item1 [item2 [...]]]
                        [[debug|optimized|general] <item>] ...)
```

And you have forgot to specify it. So instead of `target_link_libraries(${XercesLib})`, try `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${XercesLib})`.

Hopefully, that solves it.